# Why won't RabbitMQ respect my hostname on EC2/Ubuntu Lucid?

Tags: hostname, rabbitmq

I've got a fresh installation of `rabbitmq-server` on a Lucid EC2 instance. The hostname is set correctly, but rabbitmq won't pick up the hostname, and insists on calling itself `localhost`. Any idea how to convince it otherwise?

```
$ cat /etc/hostname
mifune

$ hostname
mifune

$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1 localhost mifune
...


$ sudo rabbitmqctl status
Status of node rabbit@localhost ...
[{running_applications,[{rabbit,"RabbitMQ","1.7.2"},
                        {mnesia,"MNESIA  CXC 138 12","4.4.12"},
                        {os_mon,"CPO  CXC 138 46","2.2.4"},
                        {sasl,"SASL  CXC 138 11","2.1.8"},
                        {stdlib,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","1.16.4"},
                        {kernel,"ERTS  CXC 138 10","2.13.4"}]},
 {nodes,[rabbit@localhost]},
 {running_nodes,[rabbit@localhost]}]
...done.
```

Answer (score 5):

Would you believe that switching the order of `/etc/hosts/` from:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost mifune
```

to:

```
127.0.0.1 mifune localhost
```

does the trick?

**Make sure you stop rabbitmq before doing this,** or rabbitmq will forget who it is and begin wandering around the neighborhood, pestering everybody for directions to the supermarket. It may also go catatonic and need to be completely purged and reinstalled.

Comment: Yes, I would believe this -- it's pretty much standard behaviour across most network-speaking applications.

Comment: I had assumed that it would believe ```hostname```, but I suppose that doesn't guarantee an addressable name?

Comment: Indeed; that is precisely why it's done -- because the hostname that someone might specify doesn't exist on the network.  If you want the full gory details, `hostname`(1) is full of mind-twisting.

Comment: I've run into this exact thing before with a custom Erlang application. Being that RMQ is written in Erlang, this makes sense now...